# How to build a Create View for a Many to Many relationship

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok, looks like someone should run into this, but I have not found anything that helps. This is my scenario.

I have a clients and skills model. The objective is to allow clients to rate each of a set of skills, all of them.

So, here I'll paste model, viewModel, Controller and View. at the end the crucial question

**MODEL**

```
namespace ClientSkills.Models
{
public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ClientSkills> Skills { get; set; }

}

public class Skill
{
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ClientSkills> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public int RatingId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ClientSkills> ClientSkills { get; set; }

}

public class ClientSkills
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public int RatingId { get; set; }

    public Rating Rating { get; set; }
    public Skill Skill { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}

public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Client> Client { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Skill> Skill { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rating> Rating { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClientSkills> ClientSkills { get; set; }

}

}
```

**VIEW MODEL**

```
namespace ClientSkills.Models
{
public class RateViewModel
{
    public RateViewModel()
    {
        this.Skills = new List<SkillViewModel>();
    }

    public RateViewModel(Client client)
    {
        this.ClientId = client.ClientId;
        this.Skills = new List<SkillViewModel>();
        if (client.Skills.Count == 0)
        {
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            foreach (var skill in context.Skill)
            {
                var skillVM = new SkillViewModel(skill);
                skillVM.SelectedRatingid = context.Rating.First(r => r.Name == "No aplica").RatingId;
                Skills.Add(skillVM);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in client.Skills)
            {
                var skillVM = new SkillViewModel(item);
                skillVM.SelectedRatingid = item.SkillId;
                this.Skills.Add(skillVM);
            }
        }
    }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public List<SkillViewModel> Skills { get; set; }

}

public class SkillViewModel
{

    public SkillViewModel()
    {
        Ratings = new List<Rating>();
    }
    public SkillViewModel(Skill skill)
    {
        var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        this.Ratings = context.Rating.ToList();
        this.SkillId = skill.SkillId;
        this.SkillName = skill.Name;
    }

    public SkillViewModel(ClientSkills item)
    {
        var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        this.Ratings = context.Rating.ToList();
        this.SkillId = item.SkillId;
        this.SkillName = item.Skill.Name;
        this.SelectedRatingid = item.RatingId;
    }
    public List<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
    public int SelectedRatingid { get; set; }
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public string SkillName { get; set; }

}
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
namespace ClientSkills.Controllers
{
public class RateController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Rate/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //first, we assume there is an already selected user
        var context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var client = context
            .Client
            .Include(c => c.Skills)
            .First(c => c.Name.ToLower() == "ricker");
        var model = new RateViewModel(client);
        return View(model);
    }
}
}
```

**VIEW**

This View is made creating a Create view with the wizard, deleting the useless field it creates and putting the code below

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Skill</td>
            <td>Rate</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Skills)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Skills.First(i => i.SkillName == item.SkillName).SkillName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.SelectedRatingid, new SelectList(item.Ratings, "RatingId", "Name"), "Seleccione el valor")
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

The problem is that in the `RateViewModel(Client client)` constructor in the line   `skillVM.SelectedRatingid = context.Rating.First(r => r.Name == "No aplica").RatingId;` I set a default value for the selectedRatingId property. I need to make sure all clients has all skills rated even if they forgot or bypass one of them.

When the view is loaded, and I was sure the ratesid was well set, the skill names look ok but the drop dpwn lists does not show the selected default value.

How can I make the view to bind the selectedRatingId property to the drop down list control?

Comment: I'm no .net mvc pro and sorry if this is a silly comment. Could you try another overload for ```SelectList``` constructor like this: ```@Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.SelectedRatingid, new SelectList(item.Ratings, "RatingId", "Name", item.SelectedRatingid), "Seleccione el valor")``` Notice fourth parameter for ```SelectList```

Comment: sure, I'll try and post

Comment: IT worked!!! please psot it as an answer to give your points. What is the diference? this is the first time I use that overload

Comment: The next problem is the post. Skills list is empty :(

Comment: You mean on form submission?

Comment: yes. Iwas checking, and the select is rendered this way <select name="item.SelectedRatingid" id="item_SelectedRatingid" data-val-required="The SelectedRatingid field is required." data-val-number="The field SelectedRatingid must be a number." data-val="true">, I think name should be something like Skills[i].SelectedRatingid but don't know how to do that

Comment: Not exact but quiet similar thing here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing selected value to SelectList:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.SelectedRatingid, new SelectList(item.Ratings, "RatingId", "Name", item.SelectedRatingid), "Seleccione el valor")
```

As I understand it (rightly or wrongly) that last parameter is an object if it matches with one of the options values - it is selected else the first one in the options is selected.

More info about the [Selectlist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) overload.